# Creating a BufferedImage using pixels int[]

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm using a sprite sheet and have it set up to get the pixel int[] of each sprite, I'm just not sure how to use that pixel int[] to make a seperate image.

my code:

```
i=0;
BufferedImage[] bi = new BufferedImage[];
for(y) {
   for (x) {
      int[] pixels = null;
      Vars.TILE_SHEET_BI().getRaster().getPixels(x, y, 16, 16, pixels);
      bi[i] = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
  bi[i].getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, 16, 16, pixels);
  i++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply call `getSubImage(...)` on the BufferedImage? I know that that is what I'd do, and in fact what I've done.

For example, please see the code for [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793617/522444) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793396/rendering-bufferedimage-in-jtable-cell).

Which takes this Sprite Sheet:

[image: flag sprite sheet]

and creates this GUI with it:

[image]

Comment: Oh dear lordly, yes!! Talk about a little bit of algorithm optimisation (4 to 1 lines)