# multiple Jpanel with same functionality buttons

Tags: java, database, swing, user-interface

i want to create JFrame with multiple panel each panel displaying some information from database (say product_id and description ) and each frame have a button(add to cart) which will add the information from that panel to cart table in my database how will i implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to simply things by using a JTable to display such data, with each column displaying a database field. I'd add an extra column, say a Boolean column that displays as a check box, and then assess the state of that column when needing to decide which to add to a cart.

---

**Edit**  You ask:

> how will i know how much quantity of that product is selected,

Then add a quantity field as well, perhaps one that uses a JSpinner as its editor.

> and also i am thinking to add image of that product also can i do it in Jtables

Absolutely. It knows how to display ImageIcons for instance. Please have a look at [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793617/522444) for an example.

Comment: how will i know how  much quantity of that product is selected and also i am thinking to add image of that product also can i do it in Jtables

Comment: how can i add checkbox in a Jtable?

Comment: @user3430383: if using a DefaultTableModel, make sure that the column of interest, the one that is to display a check box is of Boolean type. Then override the model's `getColumnClass(int columnIndex)` to return `Boolean.class`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a JPanel (called PanelButton) which contents [Add to cart] button.

In other JPanels, you add PanelButton.

So, by this way, you can reuse your button without implement a lot of [Add to cart] button for each panel.

Comment: `you can reuse your button` You can't reuse a button. A Swing component can only be added to a single container. You can create an ActionListener and share the ActionListener for all buttons.

Comment: @camickr: or better an AbstractAction.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yes, ActionListeners should be a thing of the past :)