# how to set jLabel into jTable cell and fetch image data from mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have saved blob data into mysql database and now I want to retrieve image into a jlabel. This jlabel will be inside jtable cell. I have tried this way and image does not show from database. How can I do that, need some suggestion. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Photo");

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/cancel.png")));
        return lbl;
    }

    public JLabel setImage(JTable table, JLabel lblImage) {
        lblImage = (JLabel) getTableCellRendererComponent(table, lblImage, getFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(),
                isFocusOwner(), ERROR, ABORT);

        return lblImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this question about getting an image from a database or putting an image in a `JTable`?

Comment: `JTable` can handle `Icon` cell types automatically, no need for a custom renderer.  `DefaultTableCellRenderer` also extends from `JLabel`, so no need to use your own

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069359/trying-to-retrieve-both-text-and-blob-from-mysql-to-jtable/35072936#35072936)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering BufferedImage in JTable cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793396/rendering-bufferedimage-in-jtable-cell)